# Detecting two windows of a process

Tags: c#, windows, process

Let's say I have 2 pdf documents and I've opened them with acrobat fine reader. So I have 2 different windows. But when I use this code:

```
foreach (Process p in Process.GetProcesses("."))
{
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\r\n");
        Console.WriteLine("\r\n Window Title:" + p.MainWindowTitle.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("\r\n Process Name:" + p.ProcessName.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("\r\n Window Handle:" + p.MainWindowHandle.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("\r\n Memory Allocation:" + p.PrivateMemorySize64.ToString());
    }
    catch { }
}
```

It gives me only the last selected window of acrobat. But I need both of them, thank you.

Comment: You might want to enumerate before looping. `Process.GetProcesses(".")` will be called on every loop.

Comment: @ColeJohnson No it doesn't - it enumerates the result of that call, which is an array (`IEnumerable<Process>`) - the call only happens once.

Comment: @ReedCopsey oh whoops. Silly me. Its a `foreach`. Not a `for`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Process` will only provide the "main" window handle, not each window.

You can accomplish this via the Windows API and PInvoke, however.  [EnumWindows](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.enumwindows) will let you enumerate the windows opened on the system.  You can then use [GetWindowThreadProcessId](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.getwindowthreadprocessid) to see if the Window belongs to your process.

At that point, you'll have the window handle for each window of the process.  Using the Handle, you can call [GetWindowText](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.getwindowtext) to get the window title.